# Problems running app on actual device

Tags: android, xamarin, deployment, crash, archive

OK, please take it easy on me, I am new to the whole Xamarin community. I have built a simple calculator app using MVVMCross. When I run the app in an emulator everything works great. It still needs some UI attention, but functionally it all works. When I go to archive it and make an install on my phone, it installs just fine. The issue is when I go to run it. As soon as it opens I get an error message. "Calculator.UI.Droid has stopped" Open app again. I have gone through everything I can find online to do this and nothing is working.

Here is my setup:
Visual Studio 2017 Community with latest updates
Windows 10 with latest updates
Latest Java SDK

Project Properties:
Compile using Android Version 7.1 (Nougat)
Minimum Android Version 5.0
Target Android Version 7.1
Use Fast Deployment - false
Generate one package (.apk) per selected ABI - unchecked
Enable ProGuard - checked
Linking - SDK and User Assemblies

Android Phone:
Google Pixel 2 with latest updates.

Any help would be appreciative. Just let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to debug the device with visual studio? This will most likely return an exception that you can work with.

Comment: I have not.  I ran everything through an emulator seeing if everything worked.  I am new to Android Development and honestly have not figured out to Debug it yet.  At this point I write a little and then deploy it to an emulator to see if it will work.  I'll see if I can figure it out though.  Thanks

Comment: You should be able to just connect your Android device via USB to your computer and have it appear in the Start list in Visual Studio (assuming you've chosen the Android project as your startup project in your solution). Just click start in VS and watch the output window for clues or error messages.

Comment: App runs just fine in debug mode.  When I set it to release mode it crashes and Visual Studio is not giving me anything other than Android application is debugging.  I did change the Linking option to be none like it is for debug and that did not help.  Thanks for the help

Comment: It would appear from looking at the log that I have dll files that are missing some how.  I guess I am going to spend my day trying to figure out why.  Thanks again for your help.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I myself are also using Xamarin, and quite often I get this problem, most times it is related to the code, so please make sure that's the case.

comment out your calculator stuff, and try running the basic app on your physical device. if that works try to find the problem, idk if you can use breakpoints because your problems happens on boot.

Comment: I did run a basic starter app and it installed and ran just fine.

Comment: mhh, try debugging your code so you know which block causes the problem, then post the code and we might be able to help.